# why optional appears when forming a string from an Int

Tags: swift, option-type

I have this simple class:

```
import UIKit

let builtIn = MyClass(n1: 1)
print("DeviceA: \(builtIn.n1)") // DeviceA Optional(1)

class MyClass: NSObject {
    var n1: Int!

    init(n1: Int) {
        super.init()

        self.n1 = n1
    }
}
```

Why is it `DeviceA Optional(1)` on the console while `n1` is not optional?

I could fix this by `print("DeviceA: \(builtIn.n1!)")`. But I just don't understand why `Optional` is there.

Thanks,

Comment: @ShamasS: in `print("DeviceA: \(builtIn.n1)")`, I don't mean to convert `String` to `Int`, instead, I want to convert from `Int` to `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared n1 as an implicitly unwrapped optional:

```
var n1: Int!
```

This means n1 is still an optional, but you are promising the code that it will be non-nil. In order to avoid the optional state you would need to declare at as:

```
var n1: Int
```

In that case you either need to make sure to initialize it in your init() function or provide a default init like this:

```
var n1: Int = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`n1` is an **implicitly unwrapped optional**.

When printed, it shows that it is, in fact, an optional, even though it behaves like a non-optional variable when used elsewhere.

Check the Swift syntax of optionals [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330).